# run "clean-up": Job failed: exit status 1

Tags: ionic-framework

I have Ionic pro, packaging for Android keeps failing with the following output:

```
$ run "clean-up"
Running Stage clean-up for Job: 5444336
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

The APK seems to generate correctly, but after the APK is generated this clean up command is attempted and fails.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm having the same issue and the Ionic Pro package log is completely useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response from Ionic support:

> I see you're using cordova-android 7.0.0. Unfortunately v7 isn't yet supported for package builds. You'll need to revert to v6.4.0 to complete the build. Have a look at this article for more details.

Comment: Which article ?